# How to decode google search reseults without API

Tags: python, google-search

I would like to decode the search results. I know there is an ajax API provided by Google, but it only gives you 32 results. 
I also know theres a library 'Xgoogle' written in python by Peteris Krumins, but it was written in 2009 so nowadays it doesnt work as well.
So is there a way to do this, in python, php, javascript?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. I believe that mentioned package was based on Google Search API, which [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/web-search/?csw=1) starting from November 1, 2010.

And automatic querying of google search page is prohibited by google: you'll be considered a bot and a captcha inquiry will be added to each search result.

You might want to consider other search engines (note that **some of them are paid services**):

- [Bing API](http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/dev-center)
- [Duck Duck Go API](https://duckduckgo.com/api)
- [Yahoo BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/)
- [Yandex XML](http://api.yandex.com/xml/doc/dg/concepts/about.xml)

Comment: Thanks a lot alko, now im getting hands on Bing API. Thankyou

Comment: @BernardoMtz, You're welcome! *Standard disclaimer:* if you found question useful, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).